# How to implement spring security config to call authorization from angular site

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security

I try to make authorization from website using angular `$http` and spring `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` here is my code:

Java part:

```
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(SecurityConfig.class);

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("user").password("12345").roles("USER");
        auth.userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter bindingFilter = new CsrfTokenResponseHeaderBindingFilter();
        http.addFilterAfter(bindingFilter, CsrfFilter.class);

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .successHandler(new AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler(new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler()))
                .loginPage("/login/existinguser").and().httpBasic().and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login/existinguser").permitAll();

        if ("true".equals(System.getProperty("httpsOnly"))) {
            LOGGER.info("launching the application in HTTPS-only mode");
            http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
        }
    }
}
```

JS part:

```
  $scope.login = function (username, password) {
        var postData = 'username='+username+'&password='+password;

        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/authenticate',
            data: postData,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                "X-Login-Ajax-call": 'true'
            }
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            if (response.data == 'ok') {
                debugger;
                window.location.replace('/');

            }
            else {
                debugger;
            }
        });
    };
```

Problem is that I receive error:

```
POST http://localhost:8080/authenticate 404 (Not Found)
```

Can someone say what I need to do, to make it work?

Comment: I made tomcat configuration, to not require name. Yes I have controllers for this, just not sure that it is because of mappings. It feels like `/authenticate` not mapped.

Comment: yes I have controllers

Answer (score 0):

Hi you have to configure authentication a rest service [here](http://www.codesandnotes.be/2014/10/31/restful-authentication-using-spring-security-on-spring-boot-and-jquery-as-a-web-client/) you have complete tutorial for rest authentication in spring boot authentication - example uses jquery but it shouldn't be a problem for you to change js part to angular

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with the csrf token. If you are sure with your controller, post method, then you should add the csrf token to the header of ajax call like;

```
var token = $("input[name='_csrf']").val();
var header = "X-CSRF-TOKEN";
$(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
});
```

Or you can disable csrf token in your SecurityConfig class.

Answer (score 0):

You can do login form in login.ftl file like:

```
    <#-- @ftlvariable name="_csrf" type="org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfToken" -->
    <#-- @ftlvariable name="error" type="java.util.Optional<String>" -->

    <form role="form"  action="/login" method="post">
        <#--<label for="email">Email</label>-->
        <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required autofocus/>
        <#--<label for="password">Password</label>-->
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required/>
        <button type="submit"> LOGIN </button>
    </form>

    <#if error.isPresent()>
        <p>The email or password you have entered is invalid, try again.</p>
    </#if>
```

in Java (Security):

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/images/*").anonymous()
            .antMatchers("/fonts/*").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/bower_components/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/scripts/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/template/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/views/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/login?error")
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutUrl("/logout")
            .deleteCookies("remember-me")
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
```

and controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getLoginPage(@RequestParam Optional<String> error) {
    return new ModelAndView("login", "error", error);
}
```

It's work for me. I think, I help you.